# Is there any impact analysis being done for the question reputation change similar to the one done in the past?

Tags: discussion, reputation, questions, voting

[Rewarding the Questions Askers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) seems to be the opposite of [this proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42769/should-the-weight-of-question-upvotes-be-reduced). Back then, [one of the answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/42802/311064) included a nice analysis of what the effect would be when this change occurs.

I think it would be nice to have an impact analysis (something more substantial than the askers will gain more reputation which is quite obvious).

A particular point of this analysis would be the following case (questions):

- score < 0
- current reputation gained by user from the question < 0
- new reputation gained by user from the question > 0

If there are many such cases, it would significantly encourage asking bad questions.

**Question:** Is there any impact analysis being done for the question reputation change similar to the one done in the past?

Comment: Check back in another three years

Comment: it seems to being throwing the ['Optimizing for Pearls](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) theory away as well.

Comment: @Skooba - yes (did not know about this). Thanks.

Comment: I found Shog's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/42774/476162) interesting.

Comment: I'd be interesting to see how the reputation changed for different type of users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there was some kind of analysis being performed before making the announcement according to [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20191105161629/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337604/stack-exchange-is-planning-to-retroactively-change-the-vote-value-on-questio) (not sure about its validity).

However, [one of its reference is still valid](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242712/how-can-se-sites-change-their-reputation-payout/242839#242839) and provides an interesting insight:

> Putting aside the intrinsic worth of questions in relation to answers,
>   **changing the reputation payout for upvotes will likely have little, if
>   any, effect on posting or voting.** More profitable avenues to explore
>   are incentives that directly encourage upvoting good questions.