# What recurring competitions are held across various communities?

Tags: discussion, contest

A lot of communities have or have had friendly competitions, whether for best question, or best answer, or questions of a particular category, etc. etc.  I'm interested in what sites are doing other than [topic challenges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243134/162102).

I think it would be beneficial to compile a list of all the different community challenges from across SE. This would have the benefit in that if later communities want to start their own challenges, they can learn from historical or current challenges on other sites, see if mistakes/problems with other, similar challenges would apply on the current site and brainstorm ways to avoid them.

Could we compile such a list here?

Such competitions should be added in the answer below. They should be in the form of `[Site Name](link-to-competition.com)`, under the appropriate header. Depending on how the site has it set up, it could be a link to the initial rule page, or a link to a search results page with a list of the relevant competitions. By doing it in this fashion, sites which want to take advantage of these statistics can easily see which sites have done that particular type of challenge before and how they did it.

**Only challenge series should be entered.** One-off challenges (unless the intention was for a full series and it just never went anywhere) and site bounties should not be included. Further, now that I'm seeing just how broad this is, **do not post weekly topic challenges; those have their own list already**. Just about every site seems to have one. This should only be for somewhat unique challenges that various communities have come up with.

Comment: Related: [How do weekly topic challenges work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240634/how-do-weekly-topic-challenges-work)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do weekly topic challenges work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240634/how-do-weekly-topic-challenges-work)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Um...no? I’m A) not asking how they work, and B) specifically asking that answers *not* include the weekly topic challenges.

Comment: Also, with the recent edit, how is this too broad?

Comment: On this note, Winter Bash here on the meta site. It definitely inspires a competitive streak in some people as they race to get the most hats as quickly as possible, and it's unique to SE. It's just around the corner at this time and I'm really looking forward to it.

Answer (score 15):

### Best Answer Contests

- [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-contest)

### Answer Old Questions

- [Travel](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22answerathon%22+is%3Aquestion+-%22leaderboard%22)
- [Movies](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bchallenge%5D+%22monthly+answer%22)
- [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answerathon)

### Photo Competition

- [Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screenshot-of-the-week) (screenshot of the week)
- [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photo-competition)
- [Photography](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hall-of-fame) (original old competition)
- [Travel](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photo-competition)
- [The Great Outdoors](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photo-competition)

### Other

- Writing's [Topic Challenges](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topic-challenge): Write a response to the month's prompt. (Previously there were [challenges about writing main site questions](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1810))
- Advent Calendars on [Puzzling](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7413/puzzling-advent-calendar-2022) and [Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25251/announcing-code-golf-advent-calendar-2022-event-challenge-sandbox)