# Sunsetting Winter/Summer Bash: Rationale and Next Steps

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, announcements, deprecation

This year, we made the difficult decision to sunset Winter/Summer Bash. [Winter Bash](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/12/19/welcome-to-winter-bash-2012/) has been an annual event on Stack Exchange each December for the past decade.

### What are the origin and goals of Winter Bash?

Winter Bash, in its original conception, was an event that was there for fun at the end of the calendar year. This was also when contests used to be held more [frequently on individual sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240634/how-do-weekly-topic-challenges-work). Community members would participate over the course of three weeks and earn hats, which they could display on their profile avatars. Over the years, Winter Bash evolved beyond just fun and was a way to encourage participation on the platform during a time of the year when participation typically wanes. It was also viewed as a source of re-engagement as we hoped it would encourage community members who had become less engaged to start participating again and stick around long term.

After last year’s event, we analyzed some of the data, and this is what we found:

- Only 1% of community members who came to the site during Winter Bash chose to wear a hat during the event.
- The total contributions from people who were participating in Winter Bash were lower than those who weren’t participating. This means people would come, participate enough to earn a hat, and then drop off again.
- We do know that a number of community members enjoy participating in Winter Bash, but each year we receive more feedback on how the concept has grown a bit stale.

### Why is Winter Bash Being Sunsetted?

In addition to the data and feedback shared above, we also looked at how expensive it is to run Winter Bash every year. From the outside, it may seem like a simple event, but it’s actually quite complex. For last year’s Winter Bash, three engineers spent two months building, launching, maintaining, and ending the event. There were also four community managers who were heavily involved, a Product Manager, and resources from our Design, Marketing, and other teams.

In the end, the lift and time required for Winter Bash is too great for the team to take on. This year we have an even smaller number of staff members on Product, Engineering, and Community, and we had to make the call that we don’t have the bandwidth to run this event.

### Will Winter Bash Return in the Future?

Never say never, but we don’t currently have plans to bring back Winter Bash as we’ve known it. What we would like to do in the future is look into fun engagement events that wouldn’t serve as a replacement for Winter Bash but could facilitate boosting participation on the platform. If we are able to move forward with this, we’d like to make sure that these events lead to sustainable participation and re-engagement. If we saw a substantial/significant increase in participation during Winter Bash we'd have strong grounds for keeping it. Anything we try in the future, we want to make sure it is successful. We also want to work with the community to ensure that any future initiatives we take on related to engagement are meaningful to you.

Comment: is that 1% of all logged in users across the network or 1% of all visitors in general during the event?

Comment: This "The total contributions from people who were participating in Winter Bash were lower than those who weren’t participating. This means people would come, participate enough to earn a hat, and then drop off again." reads oddly.  Supporting numbers and assumptions would help.

Comment: @KevinB 1% of logged-in users.

Comment: Summer Bash? What is this?

Comment: Also I couldn't even try it. Pity. :(

Comment: @PetəíŕdTheLinuxWizard last year the event was called Winter/Summer Bash because it was held in Summer for those in the Southern Hemisphere and we wanted to recognize that.

Comment: No real comment other than :(

Comment: It's sad to lose more fun on the network. Losing this kind of stuff reinforces the [loss of that "small town" feel](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426143)/ sense of community to me.

Comment: Gosh, this would have been great news had it have been accompanied by "and so instead we'll use that engineering/product resource to fix _these bugs_ / _make these improvements_"

Comment: Winter Bash iced after frosty review. Company representatives say "the event wasn't hot enough."

Comment: Of the 99%, how many of them collected say.. more than 5/10 hats? I'd imagine theres those that like to collect the hats but not have the need to awkwardly position them on their headless avatar. (or sideways facing fox that had limited options)

Comment: Yes, the "how many wore a hat" metric is not very representative. Many people try to collect as many as possible without actually wearing them.

Comment: I hate Winter Bash with an unbashingly burning hot passion. However, I know lots of people have lots of fun with it. You can see the funny creations that people do, and how far they go to find the secret hats. It's extremely sad to see that little bit of fun die off. Besides Winter Bash, there's no events in the network. Just Q&A and corporate blah blah blah. Please reconsider this decision. (I know I'm talking to a brick wall, but well, there's hope.)

Comment: This is unsurprising if you understand the history of the event. Winter Bash started flailing after the fourth year of doing it. And after that, we started discussing whether we should kill it off instead of sinking time into it _every single year_. But at the last moment, it'd be revived. Doing the same thing over and over was boring and appealed to ever-shrinking audiences. So please don't claim it's due to one thing or another - this fate has been a long time coming. I personally find it more surprising how long it did survive.

Comment: maybe it'll return as a teams event to promote the teams product with a yearly push to get people to sign up and join the winterbash team

Comment: @animuson I understand that, but it is being removed and replaced by nothing. The (in my opinion) only network-wide event *for fun* is gone. That's all we, from this side, see.

Comment: @animuson - why would we be expected to *"understand the history of the event"*? So we're back to "Stack Overflow: Where We Hate Fun"

Comment: Maybe one of our clever users can write a Winter Bash bash script run by a cron job.

Comment: I joined the Stack Overflow mid November almost 9 years ago. The first Winter Bash I participated had the StarTrek theme and it was pretty fun experience. It definitely encouraged me to look around and read about how sites work in my efforts to earn some hats. I know Winter Bash was not perfect and occasionally even had some negative effects, but I am a bit sorry to see it go :(

Comment: I'd definitely like to see us do other fun things in the future. (What form those will take remains to be seen.)

Comment: I definitely appreciate the early notice. This is disappointing news, but not notifying us until the last minute would have greatly increased the blow, so an absolute thanks from me for notifying us very early!

Comment: @animuson it was fun the first few times, but it was certainly getting stale. I would have expected it to stop much earlier, especially given how resource-intensive it was given the description here. I suspected that SE had much more convincing data on activity and engagement that lead them to continue this, but that doesn't seem to be the case actually. I think it was a nice event the first and maybe the second time, but I don't think it can justify a yearly schedule.

Comment: A bit early (*or late*) for the "annual April Fool's day joke" innit? R.I.P. fun.

Comment: "*The total contributions from people who were participating in Winter Bash were lower than those who weren’t participating. This means people would come, participate enough to earn a hat, and then drop off again.*" When does one participate in the Winter Bash, instead of just earning hats? I just liked seeing hats pop up, but didn't really care for earning them. And I doubt active participants, who I think were generally more active users in the first place, just did it for hats. Can we see the data for this?

Comment: As a southern hemisphere dweller, I have to say: good riddance. It always irritated me no end to see this crap about hats and snowflakes in the middle of summer. Also bugged me that the opt out didn't seem to be permanent.

Comment: Is the low participation rate network wide or mostly on SO? I have been perticipating as long as I have been on the network, if not on the computer based parts of the network, and hardly ever see anybody posting during the bash without wearing a hat or hunting them.

Comment: *Sunsetting Winter/Summer Bash: Rationale and Next Steps* - there are no Next Steps in this post!

Comment: "*For last year’s Winter Bash, three engineers spent two months building, launching, maintaining, and ending the event.*" - why? It was an annual event, why wasn't this just a plug-and-play module/script? Surely the engineers weren't re-writing the whole thing every year? There's a lot I don't know about ongoing maintenance, and production, being purely a hobbyist, but this seems* like a lot of work was invested unnecessarily. (*: and, again, I know little-to-nothing about the behind-the-scenes, so I'm speaking from a level of admitted ignorance.)

Comment: @DavidThomas - Maybe not the *whole* thing, but I can see it being true. If it started as a hackathony project to bring some merriment, I doubt they would have made it truly "production ready". The hats change every year, so that's engineering effort. They likely wouldn't have wanted to clean this feature since it's only deployed (bi)yearly for a couple of weeks.

Comment: @DavidThomas I imagine this was more "let's get a load of people in who'd like to help" event management style stuff that people gravitate to in orgs (I certainly do!)

Comment: @DavidThomas: The engineers can speak to this better than I can, but I know one thing that took up the engineers' time was implementing the different hats (as StoryTeller mentioned). Since we didn't just want to reuse the same hats every year (so as to avoid the event getting stale/boring), that involved implementing at least some hats with different triggers. There was a process of the CMs coming up with a list of hat ideas, then CMs and devs narrowing those down based on how feasible they were to implement, and then devs actually implementing them – all of which took time.

Comment: @V2Blast Maybe some of these effects can actually become permanent. Like maybe CMs and devs can think about their highlight hats and maybe if they become a permanent part of SO (can be turned on/off) that would be something for increased engagement.

Comment: How many of the 1% were in, say, the top 10% of contributors?

Comment: I often feel quite left out when events are labelled according to seasons in the other half of the planet. How about running a _Summer_ Bash in December/January?

Comment: @MartinKealey That's exactly what they did, the last 1-2 years. Hence "Winter/Summer Bash" in the title of the post you're commenting on.

Comment: Maybe one of the issues is that you don't get to keep the hats after the event is over. It might be nice to be able to use them year round. On a user's profile, being able to show/display one's hat collection from different years (e.g. similar to showing the badges one has earned). Also, IMO, many of the hats had tasks that were orthogonal to one's normal usage of the site. And, after earning a secret hat, at the end of the event, the method(s) available for determining the secret activity for the hat were cumbersome to use. In short, it was a bolt on to the site.

Comment: "encourage community members who had become less engaged to start participating again and stick around long term" - IDT you want *that*. - I never wore the hats but I appreciated their existence. Who cares that there's hats at all, or if they are all the same for 10y, if they don't like it in the first place? "**the lift and time required for Winter Bash is" *what exactly*** if you just use last year's?

Comment: This post has "next steps" in the title, but I don't see anything that says what you're doing next, other than "Anything we try in the future, we want to make sure it is successful"

Comment: @j08691 "We also want to work with the community to ensure that any future initiatives we take on related to engagement are meaningful to you." is the next step. Spencer shared in his answer below that he's planning to post to share and gather ideas.

Comment: [To the death of fun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MJa8WzfwlQ)

Comment: As a southernghemispherian, "winterbash" while slapping on sunblock and wearing as little as decency allows was always a jarring disconnect.   "summerbash" on the other hand was perfectly cromulent.

Comment: Dangit, now I can no longer totally eclipse my profile picture for a month out of the year by rotating and scaling the most rectangular hat.

Comment: I enjoyed it... but, there was a but. The first two years, I earned few hats. After that, I earned simple ones, couldn't earn the criticals, let alone the secret ones. So, thereafter, I came and saw who were less active, winning like 10000s of hats... Uuurrgghhhh.. Still I will miss it :(

Comment: @Rosie How many is the *1% of community members* in absolute numbers?

Comment: How many users of SO are people who come once, ask their question without doing any research, and then are never seen again. Also, how many one-off accounts are there?  I would suggest that most of the visitors are leeches without any idea of the history and vision of the site and could care less about any other aspect of the time other than getting their question answered so they don't lose their job.  So this minority of users of the ***site*** is really the majority of the ***community***

Answer (score 210):

Let me be unpopular for a moment and say **I support this decision**.

Speaking as someone who's been participating in Winter Bash since 2014 (read: a grumpy old fart), I feel that **the interest has worn off *way* long ago**. It was fun the first couple of years for me, then for a few years I'd randomly pick up hats during the period and wear them, now in the last few years I haven't even bothered wearing hats on my profile. That means it might still be interesting for new users but not for ... perhaps the majority of us by now. Time for a change.

Also, I've noticed something that's also been mentioned by staff here on this thread: Winter Bash **used up actual *developer* and *designer* time from SE**. I don't have major problems with a fun community event using up CM time, since interacting with the community is part of their job, but other employees' time could be better spent on other things. Instead of designing a whole separate Bash site with two distinct Winter/Summer themes, why not have those staff members spend their time on giving recently graduated sites their own themes? Instead of adding temporary fun bells and whistles to our profiles, why not create new permanent badges rewarding healthy site activity?

**This isn't saying "we won't have fun events any more".** Staff have [explicitly said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/392852/278659) they'd like to have a different community-building event. To those upset about losing Winter/Summer Bash, let's engage with that process instead. Maybe we can get something even better to replace it. Maybe something that uses less developer/designer time, prioritising employee time more wisely, or something that new and old users can enjoy equally rather than the same old thing whose novelty has worn off for many of us.

Comment: "Staff have explicitly said they'd like to have a different community-building event." - It might have been better received if there was such an event *already planned* and revealed, rather than a "We're thinking until it becomes apparent that everyone has forgotten" type of situation.

Comment: @JohnP: Ymmv, but I prefer being informed as early as possible, rather than delaying the announcement until a replacement event has been planned.

Comment: I agree with @Heinzi, besides it'll probably be better that a new community-building event isn't just seen as the "Winter/Summer Bash Replacement".

Comment: @JohnP this reminds me of the new site navigation which was dropped in favor of the even newer/better site navigation only existing in the site owners’ imagination. Needless to say that this even better navigation never came.

Comment: *in the last few years I haven't even bothered wearing hats on my profile* <-- you just need a more hattable avi ;)

Comment: "_Let me be unpopular_": currently standing at `+206` to `-6`.

Answer (score 146):

As much as I may understand the decision, I'm still very sad.

Winterbash was a big part of many years of my career at Stack Overflow, and I enjoyed the work on it tremendously.

I had a lot of fun building [countdowns](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311754/understanding-the-winterbash-2015-countdown), [knitting machines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319846/winter-bash-2018-knitting), realistic [stick figure snowfights](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313077/how-does-the-snowball-fight-animation-on-the-winter-bash-page-work), realistic [snow fall animations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213043/who-made-the-2013-winter-bash-snowflake-script), and [chickens](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304285/what-is-the-chicken), and [more chickens](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304391/the-quest-for-the-winter-chicken-of-the-bash-part-2).

I enjoyed updating [FAQs with a twist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245122/why-didnt-or-did-i-or-some-other-user-get-a-hat-although-the-requirements-wer), drawing red herring hats (I'll explain that some day), [tweaking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245625/please-allow-me-to-wear-my-hat-upside-down/245795#245795) the hat placement mechanics, and when I left the company in 2019, writing down detailed documentation of how everything Winterbash-related works in our internal Stack Overflow for Teams instance.

Most of all, I enjoyed seeing how our users had fun chasing and wearing hats and [discovering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319928/the-lord-of-the-hats-the-return-of-the-chicken) the [Easter eggs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161331/the-quest-for-the-winter-unicorn-of-the-bash) I left for them.

I made a little tribute so we don't forget: **https://winterbash.rip** *

[image: screenshot of the site linked above]

**Rest in peace, Winterbash. You were awesome.**

<sub>* personal tribute, to be clear -- not endorsed by Stack Overflow Inc.</sub>

Comment: Great, you almost made me cry.

Comment: Great, how adorable. +1

Comment: A lovely tribute <3

Comment: I am glad stick figure snowfights have come into my life.

Answer (score 134):

I love community events. In fact, I would state they are somewhat crucial to a community being a community. It's why I volunteered to look into the internal question, “No Winter Bash, so what’s next?”  There is nothing quite like a group of people with shared interests getting to do things together in an enjoyable way. I would be thrilled to come up with something meaningful and fun.

I am currently looking into different kinds of community events we can run around engagement, mainly things centered around frivolous fun that are much lower lifts on our engineering teams and, ideally, things that are easily flexible to change thematically to avoid things becoming stale.

At some point, I would like to invite the community into the discussion, possibly in the form of a working group or just a general discussion on Meta, to see what y'all think about our ideas and proceed with whatever sounds fun.

Comment: Spring socks. Or funny, cute animals like spiders, that eat some bugs. Or unicorns, real unicorns instead of worthless internet points. Whatever a couple of engineers can come up with.

Comment: Seven red lines, all of them strictly perpendicular. Some with green pixels, and some with transparent.

Comment: Throwing [this community-run contest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349555/294691) out there as an example

Comment: If there's one takeaway from Winterbash for me, it's that the profile pic customisation was *fun*. It doesn't have to be hats, but having other options for customising the appearance that the card/mouseover/profile page displays is something I would like to see. Doesn't have to be "here's a colour picker, go nuts", but "Here's 8 user card background colours to choose from" would be nice.

Comment: I'd never seen the word "lift" used in this way before ("much lower lifts on our engineering teams") until both this question and this answer - what does it mean in this context?

Comment: @PhilipC [Wiktionary's noun(10)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lift#Noun) sense seems to fit: “The amount or weight to be lifted.”

Comment: "I am currently looking into different kinds of community events we can run around engagement" - No "fun" event can distract me from all of the unfun things the company did over the last years. Instead, how about an event where the company takes the concerns of quality focused experts seriously? No hats or other BS required. And you know what's more "crucial to a community being a community" than some seasonal events? Actually feeling like feedback from expert community members matters and isn't just handwaved away or ignored entirely by the company.

Comment: Also, just generally boosting engagement is NOT in the interest of the wider community. It has to be the _right_ form of engagement; we already have enough people on SO spamming useless edits to questions that should be closed without promising them a hat or some other garbage if they do that a hundred times. And based on the current track record I don't have confidence that the company will manage to launch events that promote the kind of engagement that improves the site and community.

Comment: @Mithical I love the idea of bringing back more of these community-run contests. I find them really meaningful since they are community-conceived and driven.

Comment: @spencerg what about participating in (and boosting) advent of code? Maybe let people supply their aoc login and then do more enriched/segmented leaderboards for SO people?

Comment: @PhilipC It's a description of the level of effort; a "lower lift" is a smaller level of effort or workload on the engineering team.

Comment: I'm part of the user community for Home Assistant, a popular home automation tool. There, there's a yearly event called the ["Month of 'What the Heck?'"](https://www.home-assistant.io/blog/2022/09/30/the-month-of-what-the-heck/), where users are asked to bring any bugs or missing expected features which have been bothering them, for discussion and prioritized attention. Since capacity is being freed up by ending Winter Bash, maybe Stack Exchange could consider a similar event, smashing some of the many long-stale feature requests or bug reports so as to help cultivate some community goodwill?

Comment: @Robotnik - Thing is, you can do that now by creating your own avatar/profile image and uploading it to your profile. You don't need the developers to do something special for you to achieve it. It's already there.

Comment: So, practically no one participated in the event?  Fix the event.  There are lot of developers in stack overflow so surely we can come up with one good idea.    Prove the degrees fo separation theory, pass tokens, etc.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 note my examples are about customising the user card and profile, not specifically the picture. I am aware that pictures can be updated, yes

Comment: @Robotnik - And my point is: You can do everything you are talking about by just inserting your own customized image. You don't need extra programming to make it happen (from SE's end).

Comment: @Mithical Thank you for sharing that. We have been collecting past community contests like these to look at and see what we can learn from them.

Comment: @SamHanley Interesting thank you for sharing.

Comment: So how about something more or less completely detached from the Q&A? The hat chasing always seemed artificial to me since it involved changing ones behavior on the main Q&A site. Who's saying it has to be integrated into the site and thereby take up lots of engineer time?

Comment: Like... I dunno, take a selfie of your laptop while it visits some landmark with your favourite SE community on the screen and ask a question related to the location? Like posting a programming question about the Eiffel language from the Eiffel tower. It's not hard to come up with fun contests that takes no more effort from SO the company than to host a meta thread somewhere and optionally hand out some swag to the winners.

Comment: Full Disclosure:  I have "worn" the hats out of a sense obligation because  I support the community and find tremendous value here.  That said, I found the hats to be a bit silly and certainly cryptic.

Comment: What assurance do I get that if such a conversation started here that it'd actually *lead* to something?  The rationale to do away with this event reads as if there are more pressing things you need the devs for, and I can at least *agree* with that, but I don't want to get my hopes up just to have reality remind me about this.  The company also doesn't have the most stellar track record when it comes to community-led or organized requests leading somewhere.

Comment: @Mithical good idea, I had never heard of a haiku until I came here! Unfortunately there is this site https://www.poem-generator.org.uk/haiku/

Answer (score 54):

"We have come here not to mourn Winter Bash but to bury it"

Honestly? I feel rather... meh about Winter Bash going away.

I *am* rather annoyed at the lack of community consultation, and while this is generally not a good year, between the annual April Fools day prank being cancelled, the protest action and now this. Of many years, *this* is the one that needs frivolous joy.

On one hand it was the last big *community* event, and probably the only network wide one. We'd already also lost things like the big formal graduations, site anniversaries. The company spends *millions* on big events apparently, and it's sad to see this one go.

On the other hand, it *was* getting stale - and we were recycling hats and such.

I guess the real question is - what do you think you should do instead?

Comment: I'm not sure that community consultation could've done all that much on this one. (Or at least, I'm not particularly annoyed by the lack of it.) On the community side we see the fun side (or the fading thereof...) but we don't really see the expenses side. The call "this is too expensive to keep running anymore" isn't something where we can have a proper two-sided conversation with both sides understanding each other's constraints.

Comment: I never really talked about hat rationales - rather the broader scope of 'why' winterbash was important, especially in a year where... quite a lot has gone badly.

Comment: If something isn't actually related to the core Q&A product and it is taking up developer time, then I actually think that the company doesn't need to consult the community before closing it down. Winter bash like April Fools is just fun bonus content. They wouldn't consult the community before sending out them coffee mugs and t-shirts either.

Comment: Well that stopped too. And I'd say healthy sites are more than just 'core' Q&A development. I suspect the general consensus about winterbash is "Meh" but it would still be at least asking about/communicating about it .

Answer (score 42):

All good things must come
to an end; Winter Bash, we'll
remember the fun.

No more hats, alas.
Now go and rest, Defender
of the Unicorn!

Comment: A wonderful excerpt from the writings of Winter Bashō!

Answer (score 37):

I've enjoyed Winter Bash quite a bit. It's been the highlight of more than one of my days, our own little annual celebration. (At times, it was the reason I did *anything at all*.) I'm sad to see it end.

But honestly, [this tracks](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/180189/25775). When I do something for the first time, it's a fun novelty. If I enjoy it enough, I might repeat it. But do it too often, and it becomes an *obligation* – a thing *that I do* – long past the point it ceases to be enjoyable. **Mandatory fun is not fun**. It is, in fact, very bad.

If it's not fun for y'all any more, I honestly don't care how fun it is for us. Stack Exchange Inc.'s job is to keep the Stack Exchange network up and running (and, every so often, make it better). That's the only thing that should be causing any of you distress (as staff) – and even then, only to the extent it absolutely has to.

I don't think the proportion who chose to *wear* hats is an accurate metric for either deliberate participation in, or enjoyment of, any given Winter Bash. (For instance, I would wear nothing until I got a hat I liked, then wear it upside down and as large as possible for the rest of the Bash.) It's an approximate lower bound, perhaps. **This is irrelevant.** Even if *everyone* liked it, that wouldn't matter in the slightest. If fun gets in the way of high-quality Q&A, [we hate fun](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/). If Winter Bash has become a poor use of your limited resources, that's the end of it.

I'm disappointed we're losing this tradition. If you “don’t have the bandwidth” for Winter Bash any more, be proud of your decision to stop running it, however difficult it may have been. Things change. That's okay. Thanks for running it as long as you did, and thanks for giving us this much notice of the cancellation.

P.S.: There's good odds I'll be annoyed by whatever *new* fun thing you next decide to do, however many years down the line that is. So long as it doesn't interfere with Q&A, and I can turn it off ([regardless of whether I like it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357918/308065)): go right ahead, and don't let my disapproval stop you.

---

As for next steps… [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) exists, and [we might be getting improvements to the API](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391835/308065). If we get organised enough before perihelion season, we could run our *own* Winter Bash. If we wanted to, that is. [I hear it's a lot of work.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winter-bash+bug)

Comment: Thanks for the kind words, and the constructive feedback (positive, negative, and neutral)! :)

Comment: I'm actually a huge fan of what Stack Apps does with the App of the Month and what some of our other communities do or have done in the past in terms of contests. I'd love to see if there is a sustainable way to revive some of that network wide in the future.

Comment: @Rosie it is worth mentioning that at Stack Apps we still accept [new nominations](https://stackapps.com/questions/9281/whats-the-next-script-app-library-of-the-month) for old and new apps/script/libraries to be in the spotlight as App of the Month and our community bulletin features [Calling SE APIs with Nushell (basic overview)](https://stackapps.com/questions/10180) for the month September 2023.

Answer (score 26):

I see the sunsetting of Winter/Summer Bash to be change. I try not to take issue with change, because change is inevitable. There is an issue with which I do see as an issue.

I've been a member of the Stack Exchange network for over 10 years. I joined SE for two reasons. Having been a moderator on several typical forums, I didn't like how people could just throw things out there and there seemed to be no accountability for false or incorrect information. Here on SE there was a way to deal with bad information and also to get recognized for good information. That portion of SE remains. I also liked what I perceived as the community aspect. People can come together to solve issues and learn something. This community aspect seems to be suffering and has degraded over the last few years. Maybe this is because SE has become too big? Maybe it's because leadership/management has changed which caused a change of direction? Maybe it's because world events have caused us all to re-evaluate our priorities? I don't really know. It's probably a conglomerations of things all picking at things at the same time.

Whatever reason has caused this shift, the community aspect I once enjoyed here seems to be quickly diminishing. I don't blame the death of Winter/Summer Bash as another nail in that coffin, but rather, *the lack of something to replace it*. If  Winter/Summer Bash has become stale (in all fairness, I was one of the 1% last year ... my avatar lends to wearing a hat! :o), why don't you figure out something to replace it with before you kill it off? Without a replacement, the coffin which holds community is becoming more and more sealed. Quit trying to put a death knell upon SE. Try to reinvigorate the community rather than pushing it 6' under. Without community, ***SE will fail***. Taking away more of what makes this a community without something to replace it is leading directly there.

Comment: but collectives!

Comment: "People can come together to solve issues and learn something." This hasn't changed, I don't think. Maybe you know more now, so don't learn as much? Maybe you don't have the same appetite for it as you did back then? Maybe you have less time? People change, but perceive their environment changing instead. "Things were better in the old days" is something everyone has said at some point, since the dawn of human civilization.

Comment: @CrisLuengo - I think you missed the beginning of my post. I get change. I try to understand change. I don't even have a problem with it. We all change. None of this was really my point. My point is, as more things get taken away without replacement of some type, community suffers. Plus all of the faux pas which SE corporate has done over the last few years, starting with Monica, it isn't seen to be getting better.

Answer (score 24):

### Promote the existing fun

I'll miss Winter Bash (or "Winter/Summer Bash" if you prefer). Let's do something else to keep up the spirit and also drive traffic to our sites that need it.

[Many sites have existing "fun"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322167/323179) which is organized on their meta sites: Topic challenges. Picture competitions. Favorite posts lists. Many of these posts can be enjoyed by a wider audience, and promoting them could be very simple in terms of staff involvement. The most basic option would be to feature a post about one (or several?) of these events here on Meta Stack Exchange when there's a lull in other announcements, like is the case in December/January.

This is of course motivated in part by [my own series of topic challenges](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topic-challenge), which has been usually failing to get any participants other than myself, hosted on a site where activity (and even traffic) is very low despite having a pretty universal topic — we are all here writing, after all.

Comment: RIP WB. While [Organize a Photo Competition similar to travel.meta.stackexchange.com](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3782/organize-a-photo-competition-similar-to-travel-meta-stackexchange-com): got this answer from mod: *While I like the idea (I am known to occasionally share photos in the Frying Pan), I am not sure whether we as mods have the energy to orchestrate it - or whether we even should.* from dec 2022

Comment: ^ either we have a company event like WB, or we are looking at local events on small sites organized by enthusiastic moderators/users for a minority of users, who most likely never won't get into visiting a "fellow" SE site

Comment: Another community run event is [Screenshot of the Week](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screenshot-of-the-week) on Arqade meta (currently on #98!)

Comment: SOCVR often has messages with "screenshot of the day" nominations; typically exhibiting exceptionally bad ones. I guess some beginners might find this more "toxic" than funny, but perhaps it could be turned into a teachable moment if repackaged with a different spin.

Comment: Personally, I'm definitely in support of doing more to promote (internally and externally) the various community engagement activities that our sites are already doing. :)

Answer (score 18):

This kind of for-fun project often costs more on paper, but brought a lot of morale and good will with it, which brings *back* a lot of value and energy.  While the numbers on paper make sense, it's really just unfortunate that we're not going to be having hats.

I'm not...happy about this.  I get why you're doing it, but we didn't need *this* morale obliterating news when we've (read: community and company and executive leadership) had a rocky year with each other, when the year isn't even over yet.

Comment: The apparent time costs sound very high for the level of benefit delivered. I'm more than a bit skeptical that hat-time would come around and suddenly people in the community would see the company in a new positive light, especially for an event that has gotten a bit stale. If there were some way to make it more reasonable in scope of effort I wouldn't see much harm in it.

Comment: @BryanKrause:  It was something fun to look forward to.  Even if it was a bit stale it was known, and sprucing it up is one of those perennial challenges where getting buy-in or consensus on what to do next takes time.  But to be more pointed, if the company was feeling like this was dragging on or not that exciting, **why didn't they take any of our feedback on board??**  I would imagine that we'd have some things to contribute to this discussion if it really was the case that they were running out of ways to keep it fresh.  They're not in some echo chamber, after all.

Comment: I'm sure just as many people feel like "Why are you spending developer time on hats instead of my favorite feature request"; hats-related features, fun as they might be, seem like they should be pretty low-priority to me. It would be one thing if these were little hobby projects by someone in their spare time, but instead it sounds like a pretty clunky system that took a lot of effort to run.

Comment: @BryanKrause: I'm not contending against the time/effort to run vs the apparent value, but I would adamantly reject *any* notion of this being something they deprioritize in favor of them prioritizing anything *we* want.  This is going to be time and energy going straight into their corporate priorities, which is *fine*, but I don't want it conflated that their priorities and my priorities align all that well.

Comment: They're looking at fixing long-standing website accessibility bugs, improving the API, and fixing the more irritating aspects of the left sidebar. That's not nothing.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: If that was a priority, then Winterbash would've been mothballed a long time ago with _that_ as the explicit reason instead of a "it's honestly too expensive to do this" reason. So I see the work on all of those initiatives as serendipitous rather than where the attention will really go after this is done.

Comment: @Makoto You're modelling Stack Exchange as an ideal perfectly-rational agent, whose efforts may be just as easily directed anywhere, who aligns its actions with a strategy that optimises with respect to a coherent utility function. I've never seen _any_ group do that. (Heck, it's hard enough finding a _single_ person who behaves that way.) Attention is not a fungible resource, [person-hours are not necessarily transferable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mythical_Man-Month), and not everything is part of a grand strategy.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 "[N]ot everything is part of a grand strategy." Quoted for truth — this is very hard to keep in mind, but extremely important.

Comment: They said 1% wore a hat last time. I wonder how many explicitly "hated hats". I participated in winter bash for a year or two, but I quickly ended up being annoyed by a lot of harmful behaviours it would encourage (e.g. the swarms of entitled randos demanding their messages be starred in chat for a new year's hat, and similar disruptive incentives on the main site). If more people ended up hating winter bash than loving it then axing can even be a net benefit to the community... :P

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні: I'm still taking that percentage with a grain of salt. Participation network-wide is at its lowest in December, since many of the normal site-goers are off of school or on vacation. Then factor in the even lower actual percentage of "community" that's just always around. 1% sounds low on paper, but I wonder if that's really how many daily users actually are in this so-called community. Y'know, those who care to do things here beyond finding an answer to their question.

Answer (score 10):

It is a pity. This was a good tradition. And I didn't have time to enjoy it, because I have registered just in December 2022... But the community thinks it's the right solution (+113/-53) - maybe it is?

And I hope that released resources will be used for **something useful**: for example, for bug fixes, yes?

Comment: You are not the only one. Literally I didn't even knew what is it but I was hoping to try it. Aaaand... Sunsetting Winter/Summer Bash :'(

Answer (score 8):

I never participate in it myself, but I always enjoyed seeing other people finding clever ways to spice up their profiles with hats. Although I'm not too sad to see Winter Bash go, I'm excited at the prospect of something fresh ultimately replacing it. It would be interesting to see something integrated with the theme of the sites involved.

> After last year’s event, we analyzed some of the data, and this is what we found:

I'd be curious to know how this compares to past years.

Answer (score 8):

It'll feel a bit less like Christmas without the hats on Stack Overflow, but I admit that I, too, have been less engaged with them in the past couple years. As part of a team that has had to make difficult cuts to product features and personnel over the past year, and needing to do more with less at times, I understand SO's position.

Perhaps an advent-calendar-style event would make sense this year.

[image]

Setting up a separate site page wouldn't require too much effort. Each day leading up to Christmas there could be a link to a new download, etc. (Maybe one day could be the SVGs or renders for Winter Bash hats from prior years, so people can add them to their profile pictures manually.)

Even just a bit of a style change to the site in general to mark the holidays would add a bit of cheer.

Answer (score 7):

In the realm of knowledge's vast expanse,

Where questions abound and answers commence,

A festive tradition we'll miss,

Winter Bash, with its hats and its bliss,

Now bids us farewell, a poignant glance.

Comment: ... you forgot the last line "That all started with the big bang" :P

Comment: @SPArcheon Good one

Answer (score 6):

To be honest, when I first joined and was using the Stack Exchange network it was a particular community (the *[Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour)* site) that drew me in as I had bought one of the <s>beasties</s> (Ooops, that more accurately refers to [FreeBSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD) - which *[Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)* has been helpful for) *devices* and was seeking out advice and information. However over time that pursuit has waned, yet for several years Winter/Summer Bash pulled me back into visiting the communities.

Now, though, with some (because I haven't been around much to catch **all** I suspect) of the "upsets" that have occurred around here, my response to a future devoid of festive headwear is sadly now a resounding, ***meh***! I mean, I probably won't even try to kindle a small spark of festive interest in SE at the end of 2023—sadly I suspect I won't be the only one.

Comment: Correct! You're not the only one. :/

Comment: To counteract anecdata with anecdata: 

I never really got Winter/Summer Bash - I've always thought of it a silly thing that wasn't even fun. And given the numbers above, I suspect we're more than you :-) 

Note: I was not involved at all in the decision!

Comment: Personally, I enjoyed Winter Bash as a regular user (mostly on RPG.SE) the first time I learned about it – but the hats also didn't do much to increase my participation on the site. I might have sought out the hats the first time around, but some of them were contingent on me having good questions or answers to post on the site, and it was hard for me to find things to post beyond my regular activity on the site. And once the novelty wore off after my first WB, it did even less for me.

Comment: I liked that it was a "fun" thing the company did, but the hats weren't a big factor. Something like the knitting "minigame" (or similar) was definitely more fun to me than just the same sort of hat-collecting mechanism every year.

Answer (score 5):

Discovered Meta Stack Exchange during Winter Bash 2015, previously hung out on Meta Stack Overflow. Joined Meta Stack Exchange 8 years ago and posted my first answer here.

Winter Bash drew me into MSE, creating some wonderful #WinterBashMemories.

[image: Winter Bash]

Answer (score 3):

No more New things..
No more New stuffs..
No more New Hats forever..

No New Questions..
No New Users..
No News

:(

Answer (score -10):

##### Good riddance!

I can't be the only one who loves the Stack Exchange network because of its focus on *questions and answers* instead of the traditional forum or mailing list that invariably end up with a small clique of users who keep butting in on every thread without much to say except they have nothing better to do.

If I remember correctly, that was also one of the initial goals or tool to drive up the signal-to-noise ratio—reduce the social networking to the minimum necessary level. There should not *be* a community; there isn't any need for one!

Comment: Re *"end up with a small clique of users"*: I think that happens as well on the smaller Stack Exchange sites

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum I agree, but there they still tend to add value by giving straight answers to the questions posted, and they can't easily push out others who want to answer - other than giving a better answer!

Comment: I think you've missed that the question and answer bit doesn't exist without the support _from the community_; that's kinda the whole backbone of the Stack Exchange model.

Comment: @zcoop98 Wrong. The content of the question is what matters, not who asks it or what kind of relation they have to the unknown people who knows the answer. The same goes for those who know the answer to the question and decides to write an answer. Their relation to OP, other people here, or the company, has no significance to the quality of the answer. Joining is free and effortless, and unnecessary for reading. This is why Stack Exchanged prevailed over the old forum model.

Comment: Your description of the asker/answerer element of the site is accurate but it misses out on a lot of the core functionality of how the platform works. While many people are happy to ask and answer - there are many others who don't wish to create content but still want to support the site. These are often referred to as curators - people who vote, close, delete, edit... all extremely necessary tasks and things missing in many other platforms. Without these, I'd argue SO/SE would have failed. Thing is, that can get kinda lonely and determining how to properly curate isn't a one-person task.

Comment: So people who hang around form communities to consult with each other and determine some norms for the platform and moderation policy. That's where Meta came from originally (as a replacement for [UserVoice forums](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367204/what-happened-to-stackoverflow-uservoice-com))... and people have consistently found meta to be a great place for this purpose. These policies are a core part of the sites here and without community determining those norms, I don't think the sites would be as successful. ... and then we added Chat. The third place.

Comment: Chat is a place to discuss questions and answers, site policy and norms, and a place to just relax and get to know the other people participating on the site or network. Many community projects that make moderation and spam prevention possible wouldn't exist without chat and so to imply that community isn't a core element of the site fails to recognize that. Can you participate on SE/SO without any of that - absolutely! and many do. But to imply that it's not part of the site is to look only at the surface of the water and say that there are no fish.