# Will Stack Exchange be running something for April Fools in 2024?

Tags: discussion, support, winter-bash, fun, april-fools

Earlier this year, [Philippe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/15111177/philippe) created [a post on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/423947) stating that SE wouldn't be running an April Fools joke this year.

Admittedly, that post did end with

> We hope to continue celebrating April Fools' Day in the future, and we look forward to bringing you more fun in the years to come.

However, it was [announced that the Winter/Summer Bash is canceled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392846/sunsetting-winter-summer-bash-rationale-and-next-steps), and given that a lack of available resources was cited as a reason, I'm wondering if that also applies to April Fools.

Will SE be doing an April Fools joke in 2024? Or is that also going to be stopped/paused?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We are not having an April Fools' prank this year. [I posted here with more details.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/398249/no-april-fools-2024-prank-rationale-and-next-steps)